# cannot retrieve data from the database to be used as a variable in looping

Tags: vb.net

I was making a forward chaining program, there was a little mistake in running looping to find the final result.

I want to retrieve data from the database as a benchmark for queries to loop, but the data i want to use doesn't appear.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class frmkonsultasi

    Dim idgejala, idpenyakit, nmpenyakit, konsul As String
    Dim idkonsul As String
    Dim tanggal As Date
    Dim jmlh, total  As Integer


    Private Sub frmkonsultasi_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        koneksi()
        nootkonsul()
        tanggal = Now.Date
        tampil()
    End Sub

    Sub nootkonsul()
        comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("select*from diagnosa order by iddiagnosa desc", cn)
        drkonsul = comkonsul.ExecuteReader
        drkonsul.Read()
        If drkonsul.HasRows Then
            idkonsul = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right("0000" & Trim(Str(Val(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(drkonsul.Item(0), 5)) + 1)), 5)
        Else
            idkonsul = "00001"
        End If
        drkonsul.Close()
    End Sub

    Sub tampil()
        'drkonsul.Close()
        Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

        dagejala = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM gejala order by idgejala asc", cn)
        dtgejala = New DataTable
        dagejala.Fill(dtgejala)
        gridkonsul.DataSource = dtgejala

        gridkonsul.Columns.Add(chk)

        gridkonsul.Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID GEJALA"
        gridkonsul.Columns(1).HeaderText = "NAMA GEJALA"
        gridkonsul.Columns(2).HeaderText = "PILIH"

        gridkonsul.Columns(0).Width = 100
        gridkonsul.Columns(1).Width = 400
        gridkonsul.Columns(2).Width = 80

        gridkonsul.Columns(0).Visible = False


        gridkonsul.AllowUserToAddRows = False


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnprose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnprose.Click
        If Textnama.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Masukan Nama")
            Return
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = idkonsul
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To gridkonsul.Rows.Count() - 1
            Dim z As Boolean
            z = gridkonsul.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            If z = True Then
                idgejala = gridkonsul.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                'proses simpan
                comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("insert into ddiagnosa values('" & idkonsul & "','" & idgejala & "')", cn)
                comkonsul.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next
        'mencari jumlah gejala
        comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("select count(idgejala) from ddiagnosa where iddiagnosa='" & idkonsul & "'", cn)
        drkonsul = comkonsul.ExecuteReader
        drkonsul.Read()
        If drkonsul.HasRows Then
            jmlh = drkonsul.Item(0)
        End If
        drkonsul.Close()


        comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("select iddiagnosa from ddiagnosa where iddiagnosa='" & idkonsul & "'", cn)
        drkonsul = comkonsul.ExecuteReader
        drkonsul.Read()
        If drkonsul.HasRows Then
            konsul = drkonsul.Item(0)
        End If
        drkonsul.Close()
        'TextBox1.Text = konsul

        comaturan = New MySqlCommand("select idpenyakit,nmpenyakit from vaturan group by nmpenyakit having count(idgejala)='" & jmlh & "'", cn)
        draturan = comaturan.ExecuteReader
        draturan.Read()

        If draturan.HasRows Then
            Do While draturan.Read()
                idpenyakit = draturan.Item(0)
                nmpenyakit = draturan.Item(1)
                draturan.Close()
                total = 0

                'mencari gejala per penyakit
                comaturan2 = New MySqlCommand("select idgejala from vaturan where idpenyakit='" & idpenyakit & "'", cn)
                draturan2 = comaturan2.ExecuteReader
                draturan2.Read()
                If draturan2.HasRows Then
                    Do While draturan2.Read
                        idgejala = draturan2.Item(0)
                        draturan2.Close()

                        comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("select * from ddiagnosa where iddiagnosa='" & idkonsul & "'and idgejala='" & idgejala & "'", cn)
                        drkonsul = comkonsul.ExecuteReader
                        drkonsul.Read()
                        If drkonsul.HasRows Then
                            total = total + 1
                        End If
                        drkonsul.Close()

                        If total = jmlh Then
                            comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("insert into diagnosa values('" & idkonsul & "','" & Format(tanggal, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "','" & Textnama.Text & "','" & nmpenyakit & "')", cn)
                            comkonsul.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            GoTo selesai
                        End If
                    Loop
                    draturan2.NextResult()

                End If
                draturan2.Close()
            Loop
            draturan.NextResult()
            draturan.Close()

            'menyimpan tidak ditemukan
            comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("insert into diagnosa values('" & idkonsul & "','" & Format(tanggal, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "','" & Textnama.Text & "','" & nmpenyakit & "')", cn)
            comkonsul.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Else
            MsgBox("Penyakit Tidak Ditemukan", , "Info")
            Return
        End If


selesai:
        comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("select nmpenyakit from diagnosa where iddiagnosa='" & idkonsul & "'", cn)
        drkonsul = comkonsul.ExecuteReader
        drkonsul.Read()
        If drkonsul.HasRows Then
            MsgBox("Penyakit : " & drkonsul.Item(0))
        End If
        drkonsul.Close()

    End Sub
```

the problem is in this loop, I want to use "idpenyakit" and "nmpenyakit" to do the loop again in the next query, but the data is empty so the loop fails.

before I have tried to retrieve data outside the loop data can be used, but when in the loop the data becomes empty

```
comaturan = New MySqlCommand("select idpenyakit,nmpenyakit from vaturan group by nmpenyakit having count(idgejala)='" & jmlh & "'", cn)
            draturan = comaturan.ExecuteReader
            draturan.Read()

            If draturan.HasRows Then
                Do While draturan.Read()
                    idpenyakit = draturan.Item(0)
                    nmpenyakit = draturan.Item(1)
                    draturan.Close()
                    total = 0

                    'mencari gejala per penyakit
                    comaturan2 = New MySqlCommand("select idgejala from vaturan where idpenyakit='" & idpenyakit & "'", cn)
                    draturan2 = comaturan2.ExecuteReader
                    draturan2.Read()
                    If draturan2.HasRows Then
                        Do While draturan2.Read
                            idgejala = draturan2.Item(0)
                            draturan2.Close()
```

for the connection, adapter, datareader etc I place it in the module.
each table in database uses its own datareader

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module Module1
    Public cn As MySqlConnection

    Public drpenyakit As MySqlDataReader
    Public dapenyakit As MySqlDataAdapter
    Public compenyakit As MySqlCommand
    Public dtpenyakit As DataTable

    Public drgejala As MySqlDataReader
    Public dagejala As MySqlDataAdapter
    Public comgejala As MySqlCommand
    Public dtgejala As DataTable

    Public draturan As MySqlDataReader
    Public daaturan As MySqlDataAdapter
    Public comaturan As MySqlCommand
    Public dtaturan As DataTable

    Public draturan2 As MySqlDataReader
    Public daaturan2 As MySqlDataAdapter
    Public comaturan2 As MySqlCommand
    Public dtaturan2 As DataTable

    Public drkonsul As MySqlDataReader
    Public dakonsul As MySqlDataAdapter
    Public comkonsul As MySqlCommand
    Public dtkonsul As DataTable

    Public drsolusi As MySqlDataReader
    Public dasolusi As MySqlDataAdapter
    Public comsolusi As MySqlCommand
    Public dtsolusi As DataTable

    Sub koneksi()
        Try
            Dim str As String
            str = "server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=karet2;allow user variables=true"
            cn = New MySqlConnection(str)
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                cn.Open()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Koneksi Error", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

I no longer know how to solve this error, I beg for your help with this problem

and sorry for this very bad English

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively skipping your first row by calling `read()` twice. Remove the call to `read()` before the loop.

Remove the readers from `Module1` & wrap them as `Using`:

```
comaturan = New MySqlCommand("select idpenyakit, nmpenyakit from vaturan group by nmpenyakit having count(idgejala)='" & jmlh & "'", cn)

Using draturan as MySqlDataReader = comaturan.ExecuteReader()    
    If draturan.HasRows() Then
        Do While draturan.Read()
            idpenyakit = draturan.Item(0)
            nmpenyakit = draturan.Item(1)
            total = 0

            'mencari gejala per penyakit
            comaturan2 = New MySqlCommand("select idgejala from vaturan where idpenyakit='" & idpenyakit & "'", cn)

            Using draturan2 as MySqlDataReader = comaturan2.ExecuteReader()
                If draturan2.HasRows Then
                    Do While draturan2.Read()
                        idgejala = draturan2.Item(0)

                        comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("select * from ddiagnosa where iddiagnosa='" & idkonsul & "'and idgejala='" & idgejala & "'", cn)

                        Using drkonsul As MySqlDataReader = comkonsul.ExecuteReader()
                            If drkonsul.Read() Then
                                total = total + 1
                            End If
                        End Using

                        If total = jmlh Then
                            comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("insert into diagnosa values('" & idkonsul & "','" & Format(tanggal, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "','" & Textnama.Text & "','" & nmpenyakit & "')", cn)
                            comkonsul.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            'GoTo selesai    'Don't use GoTo
                        End If
                    Loop
                End If
            End Using
        Loop

        comkonsul = New MySqlCommand("insert into diagnosa values('" & idkonsul & "','" & Format(tanggal, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "','" & Textnama.Text & "','" & nmpenyakit & "')", cn)
        comkonsul.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        MsgBox("Penyakit Tidak Ditemukan", , "Info")
        Return
    End If
End Using
```

It will also fail because you are attempting to close the reader while still reading from it. I've removed `draturan.close()` from the loop. `comaturan2` will need to use another reader.

Comment: I have tried to disappear the first read (), draturan.hashrows become unreadable so that it becomes an error, this message appears:
MysqlException wan unhandled:
Invalid attempt to read when the reader is closed.

Comment: and I have tried adding a new reader before comaturan2, the data remains empty

Comment: @edrifils I've updated the answer. If you wrap the readers in `Using` blocks you'll be able to use `HasRows()` before doing your `Read()` loops.

Comment: I have tried "using" for every datareader, and this error appears:
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first. at this `Using draturan2 As MySqlDataReader = comaturan2.ExecuteReader()
                        If draturan2.HasRows Then
                            Do While draturan2.Read()
                                idgejala = draturan2.Item(0)`

Comment: Add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to your connection string to get around this.

Comment: I use mysql for the database, and from what I read it seems mysql doesn't support using MultipleActiveResultSets, maybe there are other ways to overcome this